# Coffesscript variables in ruby code pieces

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, erb

I'm just trying to call rails helper from my coffeescript.

The problem is that coffee variables are unavailable in ruby code pieces that are in `<%= ... %>` blocks. And if they are processed with `#{}` it translates to JS in a wrong way.
So, let me illustrate. This is a piece of `.js.coffee.erb` file:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include InputsHelper } %>
$('#input_input_type').change ->
  t = $('#input_input_type').val()
  $('.input_address .help-block').html('<%= input_type_hint(t) %>')
```

This code produces such error: `undefined local variable or method 't' for #<#<Class:0x007f5e75ebd860>:0x007f5e785d1410>`

Ok, let's put 't' into `#{}`:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include InputsHelper } %>
$('#input_input_type').change ->
  t = $('#input_input_type').val()
  $('.input_address .help-block').html("<%= input_type_hint(#{t}) %>")
```

This translates to JS in a wrong way. The last string looks like this:
`$('.input_address .help-block').html("<%= input_type_hint(" + t + ") %>");`
Quotes are broken, so it causes rails to fall with the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' ; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__) ^
```

In that way I don't know how to manage with this. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are trying to execute a server-side method from the client-side

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this.

The problem is that the coffee script executes in the browser, but the stuff in the `<%= ... %>` executes on the server while the server builds the coffeescript.

So when you say `input_type_hint(t)` this is running on the server, but the poor sad server doesn't have a clue what "t" is.

To make this work you are going to have recode the entire `input_type_hint` method in coffeescript, so that it can run in the browser too! (and then it won't be in the `<%= =>` thingy.

By the way you might want to check out http://ruby-hyperloop.io as instead of using coffeescript you just write ruby everywhere, and you basically don't need this clumsy ERB business.